# How do I get a friendly error page to replace the asp.net error page for url "WEB-INF./web.xml"?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, pci-dss

This url is part of a pci compliance scan and it is flagging the very sparse asp.net error page returned, which on the live site is a 500 status code and the text

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

When running the site in visual studio I however get a 404 and the text

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /WEB-INF./web.xml
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

I've tried ignoring that url in routing and mapping it to our 404 route `/error/not-found`, we have custom errors on with a default redirect to `/error/internal`. I also tried using a location tag to deny access, blocking it with request filtering, and using a handler with that path to catch the request.

I tried this rewrite, also tried the same rule blocking and redirecting but I still get the same asp.net error page. The image cut off but the rule is `^.*\./.*$` and it does match the url I am trying to filter (I've also tried simply `WEB-INF`).

[image: rewrite rule]

Any idea how I can get this url to show our custom error page?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"` to the httpRuntime node in the web.config allowed this url to get processed by ASP.Net MVC as expected.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Managed Fusion's rewriter library located here, it works similarly to redirecting through Apache configuration: http://managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/

The documentation for how to use it is here: http://managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/documentation.aspx